# Setting HTML of window.open() producing strange styling issues in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

So I have some javascript that opens a new window with no target URL. I then want to set the HTML contents of that window to be the contents of a variable, a long string of valid HTML.

```
var myHtmlHead = "<link href='/foo/my.css'...";
var myHtmlBody = "<div id='foo'>...'";
var myWindow= window.open("", "MyWindow","height=500,width=500");

myWindow.document.head.innerHTML = myHtmlHead;
myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = myHtmlBody;
```

I've cut out the content for readability. The issue is that while this works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, IE throws up a number of strange styling issues; the CSS loads but all of the DIV's are centered and overlapping and as soon as I resize the window even an pixel, it corrects itself. I think this is down to the fact that I'm loading the CSS after the window has been loaded and its not applying it correctly until the window needs to be redrawn.

Is there a way to get around this issue, or to trigger the redrawing programatically from the parent page's JS?

Edit: IE version is 11.0.9600, though it seems to work fine with Chrome 49 for example.

Comment: You should clearly delineate the version(s) of the browser with regard to such a question.

Comment: Why does your code that you are assigning to the innerHTML of the head and body element contain the tags for head and body _again_?

Comment: @CBroe Yeah, that was a mistake when writing up the example, for clarity.  The head and body doesn't include a second set of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer with continued experiment. In my own case, I was able to get much more consistent results but setting setting the `<head>` html with the CSS links AFTER setting the `<body>` content. IE seems to handle the application of the CSS much better this way round, though I cant say why.

Previously it seemed like styling (colours, fonts, backgrounds etc) were being applied, but not positional things such as sizes, locations, display layouts etc. Setting the `<head>` after setting the `<body>` content seems to address this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the point of doing this. The best practice would be that you create another page and you send variables via the URL to generate content dynamically.

In any case, Chrome and Firefox are "smarter" than IE. You must have some HTML validation problems. I can see that in your example your missing the `<doctype>`.
I recommend to print your myWindow variable and check if the HTML is valid, this can help:
https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated above it is valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a guess given the small amount of information (not a full minimal HTML text set, no details on the browser version etc. for example) Once the page renders, pick an element with layout (a div for instance) and force a re-flow of the page.  Here is a function that SHOULD do that - by the query of the property. - this is untested

```
function forceReflow(myelement){
    var myforceheight = myelement.offsetHeight;
}
```

Some background information here: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a